# WP7 fails to consume ASMX correctly ? Always get empty arrays?

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, asmx

I'm making a WP7 app, which is consuming an ASMX which I can't touch, nor adapt, since I'm not the creator, nor the provider, I'm just consuming it.

When I add the service reference to my WP7 solution (not mango - but it's the same behaviour in mango), I'll uncheck the "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" because I don't care about those.
Side Note: Even when I leave that checkbox checked it doesn't work either.

Then I add the following code to the constructor of a new WP7 page :

```
MobileWS.WebServiceSoapClient ws = new MobileWS.WebServiceSoapClient("WebServiceSoap", "http://www.somewhere.com/MobileService.asmx");
ws.getCountriesCompleted += new EventHandler<MobileWS.getCountriesCompletedEventArgs>(OnGetCountriesCompleted);
ws.getCountriesAsync("fr");
```

This goes out and fetches an array of Country objects ("fr" stands for "french", so it'll be "Etas Unis" instead of "United States")... at least that's the idea.
I even checked with Fiddler2 if it returned anything, and indeed, the ASMX responds with some XML that contains the countries.

Then my handler goes like this :

```
private void OnGetCountriesCompleted(object sender, MobileWS.getCountriesCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled == false && e.Error == null && e.Result != null)
    {
        List<MobileWS.Country> countries = e.Result.ToList<MobileWS.Country>();
        CountriesListBox.ItemsSource = countries;
    }
}
```

Unfortunatly the e.Result always returns an empty array of country objects (so non at all, but he knows there should be country objects in there, but there are 0 items in the array) !

Though, if I browse to : http://www.somewhere.com/MobileService.asmx I get the list when I invoke the getCountries function.
Even more strange, when I copy and past the exact same code in a WPF application it works like a charm, I get a filled array with 7 country objects in.

What's wrong ?

I'm refusing to parse the returned XML myself so far, but I'm feeling I will need to sooner or later because of this fail.

---

I'm pretty sure that the XML that is send back is correct, else the WPF application would have similar problems, no ?

So, looks like I'm doomed to parse it myself, then ?
I see a lot of examples on the web where they do that (parsing the XML result themselfs), so there must be a reason for that, and that reason is the one I describe above :).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a serialization issue to me. And that's about all I can say, without knowing the service or how the used classes are written/generated.

Remember that Windows Phone have limited reflection abilities, and as such can only reflect on public/internal classes, and don't support dynamics.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try to deserialize the result yourself? Granted, it's just a step away from parsing the xml manually, but it's something. If not, maybe you can find out what's going wrong.

Comment: What do you mean with "deserialize the result yourself"... I'm more or less doing that now I think, I "fill" the objects from the webservice by "parsing" WebGet's (not sure how it's called again, but it basically does a httpget).